jspdf fallback font for other language
We use custom font let's say sans that does not support chinese language. How do i add fallback option in the jspdf that it will not use sans font for chinese.
    doc.addFileToVFS('custom-sans-normal.ttf', customSansFont);
    doc.addFont('custom-sans-normal.ttf', 'custom-sans', 'normal');
    doc.setFont("custom-sans", 'normal');

